# Adding extra pages to plugin that shouldn't appear in the sidebar

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to add extra pages to my wordpress plugin and link to these pages through links, form forwards etc.

I don't want them to appear in the menu on the left - so add_submenu_page isn't the right approach.

When I try to access the page directly in the link - ie  I get a permission error ("You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.")  Also with this approach I am using a direct link to a php page, and not what wordpress seems to want which is a 'slug' or something which internally points to a page/function.

I was wondering how to add a link of the form 'admin.php?page=create_item'  and have that forward the request to a function/specific page in my plugin.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Just wanted to add putting $_GET's in the main function that runs for my first page is very cluttering.  I did implement the plugin this way but when you have 10/15 switches coming off this main function it would be a lot clearer if you could link requests to the correct places.

Comment: Add_submenu causes WP to set up permissions for that page so it's pretty much the only way.  Do you have *any* admin pages for your plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need admin pages that don't appear in the menu, use `add_submenu_page` and set `$parent` to `null`. This will create a functional page that doesn't get rendered in the menu.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpd_hidden_plugin_submenu_page' );
function wpd_hidden_plugin_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        null,
        'My Hidden Submenu Page',
        'My Hidden Submenu Page',
        'manage_options',
        'my-hidden-submenu-page',
        'my_hidden_submenu_page_callback',
    );
}
```

Users will need whatever capability you specify to visit those pages.

---

If you want to create action links that do things outside the context of the admin interface, use the [`admin_post_` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)). You use `add_action` to hook a handler function to `admin_post_` plus the slug of your custom action. Note that there are two hooks- for logged in and not logged in visitors.

```
// hook your handler function for logged in users
add_action( 'admin_post_my_action', 'wpd_my_action_function' );

//hook your handler function for non logged in users
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_action', 'wpd_my_action_function' );

function wpd_my_action_function(){
    // WordPress API works in here
    status_header( 200 );

    // do your plugin stuff

    // and always die() at the end to halt execution
    die();
}
```

To output the URL of the handler script, use [`admin_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url). Note the action slug `my_action` is passed in the `action` form element. This will trigger our hooked function.

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_action">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="some-data">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

[Adding AJAX action handlers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) is the same as the `admin_post_` action, just the tag name you hook differs, and the URL is `admin-ajax.php`.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```